# I am facing following rendering problems in Android Studio when I try to open my project. How can I resolve it?

Tags: android

I am facing following rendering problems in Android Studio when I try to open my project. How can I resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your libraries are pretty old

Please add this in  `gradle.build`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```